# Einstein Bot Training

Tags: einstein-bots

Hopefully someone who is a Einstein Bot expert reads this and can help me out.

I'm new to using the Einstein Bot Builder and our org's "Bot Training" tab has currently 100+ customer inputs which need to be re-classified (they are all classified as "Confused", without any intent suggestion assigned). Is there any way I can achieve this without having to manually re-classify all the inputs on the "Train Bot" screen?
I know I can do massive utterance imports via to the MlIntentUtterance object, and there is also the MlIntentUtteranceSuggestion object, but I'm not sure if importing data via API is an equivalent solution to using the "Train Bot" UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start extracting all the suggestions using the following query:

```
SELECT Id, Utterance, IntentSuggestion, Config.MasterLabel,ReviewStatus from MlIntentUtteranceSuggestion
```

If you would want to modify the suggestions, update the appropriate dialog for each record in the extract.

Yes, importing these records to the **MlIntentUtterance** object would be the first step to train the bot. The next step is to navigate to the *Bot builder-> Model Management -> Model tab and clicking on 'Build Model'*

Additionally, you can also handle confused dialogs by routing them to an agent. Here's a solution from the [developer cook book](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_confused.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your indications. So when the training UI is used for classifying utterances, Salesforce internally updates the MlIntentUtteranceSuggestion record and inserts a new MlIntentUtterance record, right?

Comment: You are correct.